# Unable to find dependency using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, universal-image-loader

My project build.gradle file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile project(':com_facebook_android')
   compile project(':launchpad')
   compile project(':Sliding Menu')
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
   compile files('libs/core-2.2.jar')
   compile project(':com_actionbarsherlock')
   compile project(':foursquareoauthlibrary')
   compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
   buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
   sourceSets {
      main {
         manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
         java.srcDirs = ['src']
         resources.srcDirs = ['src']
         aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
         renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
         res.srcDirs = ['res']
         assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      }

      // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
      instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

      // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
      // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
      // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
      // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
      // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
      // by a similar customization.
      debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
      release.setRoot('build-types/release')
   }
   defaultConfig {}
   productFlavors {
   }
   buildTypes {
   }
   compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   }
   dexOptions {
      preDexLibraries = false
   }
}
```

and my root build.gradle file looks like this,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-    projects/modules.
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
   }
}
```

Now the issue when I am trying to add nostra' image loader using dependency I get the following error

```
Error:Error:Failed to find: com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried and got the fix. Don't know how but it builds perfectly. All I added was

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

in my project build.gradle file.

Comment: If you don't declare at least one repository, Gradle won't be able to resolve any external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

add this your root build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

or

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```